# Can't use my webcam on Vmware Workstation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I have a Vmware ubuntu 15.04 virtual machine, and I can't acces my buil-in lenovo webcam; when i run Cheese it says: "no device found" and when i type lsusb on the terminal, no webcam is shown. I tried Vm->removable devices->Acer Lenovo EasyCamera->Connect(disconnect from host) but it said "The connection for the usb device "Acer Lenovo EasyCamera" was unsuccessful"

How can I fix this? thanks

Comment: Have you looked to see if there was a driver here: System Settings and in the Hardware section opened Additional Drivers

Comment: when i go to System Settings, in the hardware sections there are things like mouse, bluetooth, keyboard .. etc but no webcam, i am not sure if i have to install the webcam driver or Vmware can get it from Windows, and by the way i found no way to install its driver on ubuntu, even on lenovo website i found only installers for windows

Comment: Most of the time, Ubuntu will automatically have drivers available But sometimes you need to find them yourself. So if you go to "system settings" there should be an icon that looks like a PCI card and a lock with the text "Additional Drivers" under it. If you double click on that it should bring up a prompt that says "Downloading and updating package indexes", after that is done it should open and a list of hardware should show up, find the webcam, select it, and click activate

Comment: Thanks that sounds promising but i couldn't find that icon, i have attached a screenshot of the "System Settings" window: http://imgur.com/a/5l8o4

Comment: Built-in hardware, such as webcams or wifi adapters, are **not** immediately  available to VMs. If you had an USB camera, or wifi adapter, it would be simpler. 

Still you can transfer control of built-in hardware by means of the so-called `pass-through`.If you Google `vmware pass-through` you will find hundreds of links, or you may start reading from here, https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj8suLQ3qXOAhUEvBQKHXj4DPYQFgghMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fkb.vmware.com%2Fkb%2F1010789&usg=AFQjCNH1pPBRAnedx34tLszj4jDlMWR1-Q

Answer (score 2):

I have a VMWare Workstation 15 Pro on my Windows 10 (Host). I have attached an image showing the 2 easy steps:

---

[image: VMWare Workstation(15 Pro): Connect Integrated Webcam To Running Guest OS]

1. Power up your Guest OS in VMWare Workstation
2. Below the Guest OS screen, you will see a bar with hardware shortcuts for the Guest OS
3. On the bar's right there are icons for "Hard Disk", "Network Adapter", "Mouse"...
4. Find "Integrated Webcam" > "Connect (Disconnect from Host)"

This will disconnect the integrated cam of your device from your Host OS and connect it to the Guest OS. If you have multiple Guest OS running, you can simply follow the above steps to change the integrated-cam connection to any OS from previously connected Host or Guest OS.